# Anybody have CSSerializerSection from Jeff Atwood's codinghorror site?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, configuration

I would like to learn from and possibly use the section serializer that Jeff Attwood posted in his [The Last Configuration Section Handler.. Revisited](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000656.html) blog posting.  But, alas, it appears to have been lost in [the great coding horror backup failure](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001315.html).

Does anybody have a copy, or similar code that I can learn from or use?

Comment: Wow the wayback machine did have it.  I assumed that since with was a .zip file linked from the main blog posting that archive.org would not have kept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kevindtimm has the answer.  Pull the file from the internet [wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20071020021643/http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/files/CSSerializerSection.zip)